# Eventlisteners not showing in browser console

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5, progressive-web-apps, cesiumjs

I am creating a web application for `cesium JS` and have structured my project directory as follows:

```
Project
    -node_modules
    -public
          -css
          -data_3d
          -Img
          -js
             -aggregate.js
             -Eventlisteners.js
             -appCesium, etc
          -index.html           
    -app.js
    -package.json
    -package-lock.json
```

**settings for app.js:**

```
import express from 'express';
import axios from 'axios';
import cors from 'cors';

const app = express();
app.use(cors());

// Serve static HTML files
app.use(express.static("public"));
// Route for root path for index.html


import {
  extractPhenomenonNameFromDatastreamName,
  formatDatastreamMetadataForChart,
  extractPropertiesFromFormattedDatastreamMetadata,
} from "./public/js/FetchDatastreamsProcessing.js"

import { observationsArr } from './public/js/CleanObsData.js';

// Serve static CSS files
app.use("/public/css", express.static("public/css", { type: "text/css" }));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});
```

Why can't I see the console log of event listeners in the browser console
Event listeners script:

```
import axios from "axios";
import {activate3DTileFeaturePicking} from "./appCesium.js"
import { error } from "console";
const UpdateSelectedOptions = async function(){
    const selectElement = document.getElementById('drop-dowm--Buildings-select');

    selectElement.addEventListener('change', async function (){
        console.log(selectElement)
        const selectedOptions = this.selectedOptions;
        const optionSelectionArr = [];
        try{
            const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:3300/Things');
            const apiData = response.data.value
            const filteredData =apiData.value.filter(item => Array.from(selectedOptions).some(option=> option.text === item.name));
            optionSelectionArr.push(filteredData)
            // activate3DTileFeaturePicking(filteredData);
            filteredData.forEach(item => activate3DTileFeaturePicking(item))
            return optionSelectionArr;
        }catch(error){
            console.error('Error fetching data:',error);
        }
    })
}
UpdateSelectedOptions();
```

[image]

[image]

I restructured the folders to look like what I presented above and I have already tried adding this in html in the script tag as this:

```
<script>

    const UpdateSelectedOptions = async function(){
        const selectElement = document.getElementById('drop-dowm--Buildings-select');

        selectElement.addEventListener('change', async function (){
            console.log(selectElement)
            const selectedOptions = this.selectedOptions;
            const optionSelectionArr = [];
            try{
                const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:3300/Things');
                const apiData = response.data.value
                const filteredData =apiData.value.filter(item => Array.from(selectedOptions).some(option=> option.text === item.name));
                optionSelectionArr.push(filteredData)
                // activate3DTileFeaturePicking(filteredData);
                // filteredData.forEach(item => activate3DTileFeaturePicking(item))
                console.log(optionSelectionArr);
            }catch(error){
                console.error('Error fetching data:',error);
            }
        })
    }
    UpdateSelectedOptions();
</script>
```

Which works but when I add it as a path (example,`<script src="./js/EventListeners.js" defer type="module"></script>`) it doesn't show in browser console. I need to be able to see if the Things data array are loaded when I select the buildings and should highlight the 3d objects in cesium when they are clicked

Comment: You cannot import **npm** modules in the browser like that (`import axios from "axios";`). You'll have to transpile the code using something like **webpack**. Or, just use `fetch` instead of `axios` because you can import `./appCesium.js` in the browser and `import { error } from "console"` doesn't seem to be used anyways.

Comment: Hi, using images for code or errors causes a lot of problems. Use images only to illustrate graphical issues. Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7353417).  Thank you